# How to disconnect one dropbox account from the app?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am using [this sample](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android) to browse a dropbox account and I wanted to add a feature to provide an option to logout the current user and login to a new account. For this I found out that I can use `dbxClientV2.auth().tokenRevoke()`

So I changed DropboxClientFactory to;

```
public class DropboxClientFactory {
    private static DbxClientV2 sDbxClient;
    public static void init(String accessToken) {
        if (sDbxClient == null) {
            DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("examples-v2-demo")
                    .withHttpRequestor(OkHttp3Requestor.INSTANCE)
                    .build();

            sDbxClient = new DbxClientV2(requestConfig, accessToken);
        }
    }

    public static DbxClientV2 getClient() {
        if (sDbxClient == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Client not initialized.");
        }
        return sDbxClient;
    }

    public static void revokeClient(final CallBack callBack) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    sDbxClient.auth().tokenRevoke();
                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    Log.e("Dropbox", "Access Revoke Exception", e);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                sDbxClient = null;
                if (callBack != null)
                    callBack.onRevoke();
            }
        }.execute();

    }

    public interface CallBack{
        void onRevoke();
    }
}
```

and in DropboxActivity I added `revokeToken` function. Whole Modified `DropboxActivity` is as follows

```
public abstract class DropboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("dropbox-sample", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String accessToken = prefs.getString("access-token", null);
        if (accessToken == null) {
            accessToken = Auth.getOAuth2Token();
            if (accessToken != null) {
                prefs.edit().putString("access-token", accessToken).apply();
                initAndLoadData(accessToken);
            }
        } else {
            initAndLoadData(accessToken);
        }
    }

    private void initAndLoadData(String accessToken) {
        DropboxClientFactory.init(accessToken);
        PicassoClient.init(getApplicationContext(), DropboxClientFactory.getClient());
        loadData();
    }

    protected abstract void loadData();

    protected boolean hasToken() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("dropbox-sample", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String accessToken = prefs.getString("access-token", null);
        return accessToken != null;
    }

    protected void removeToken(DropboxClientFactory.CallBack callback) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("dropbox-sample", MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().remove("access-token").apply();
        DropboxClientFactory.revokeClient(callback);
    }
}
```

So on Logout I call

```
removeToken(new DropboxClientFactory.CallBack() {
    @Override
    public void onRevoke() {
        onResume();
    }
});
```

This works fine when we didn't login in the current session of the app. But if I signed in and generated a token from the same session of the app, and revoked that token later, `Auth.getOAuth2Token()` still returns the that token which is revoked earlier, no matter we how many times logged in from another account later.  This logged in tokens in the same session of the app cannot removed from `Auth` class too. How to fix this? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: For clarity, can you share the code and the resulting error for the part that fails when you say "in the current session of the app it tries a token and returns its an invalid token"?

Comment: The `tokenRevoke` method revokes the token with the server, and the `getOAuth2Token` method just retrieves the token from an auth activity. It looks like you're already removing the token from persistence (`SharedPreferences`), but that issue may be that you aren't throwing away the existing client with the revoked token in memory?

Comment: Yes. `tokenRemove` just revokes the token in the server. And I am removing the token in `SharedPreferences`. But how to throw away the exisiting token? `Auth` is a class provided dropbox-api and it doesnt provide exact way to throw away the existing keys. I'm kind of new to drop-box api

Comment: I mean in your code, you should throw away your `sDbxClient` object, since that has the old token.

Comment: Thanks. That's something I missed on my account. I added it as u instructed. Still it does not solve the issue though. Auth class still have the logged in token.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. When/where are you calling `getOAuth2Token`? I don't see it in your code snippets. That should only be called after the user goes through the app authorization flow.

Comment: it is actually called through Dropbox Sample [link](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android) given at the top of the question. I added that code snippet (`DropboxActivity`) in the edited. I call `onResume` in `onRevoke` method of the `Callback` inteface of `DropboxClientFactory`

Comment: @Greg thanks its resolved. What u said was exactly the issue. I actually call `onResume` after revoking the token in turn which call for `Auth.getOAuth2Token()`. So as a solution i keep track which tokens are revoked and call it only if only its not one of the revoked... Thanks a bunch..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I solved it setting the static AuthActivity.result variable to null on DropboxActivity file:

```
protected void removeToken(DropboxClientFactory.CallBack callback) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("dropbox-sample", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().remove("access-token").apply();
    com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity.result = null;//FIX
    DropboxClientFactory.revokeClient(callback);
}
```

And it works!

You will logout successfully.

Why?

The Auth.getOAuth2Token() method returns the result of Login Activity, even you had logout it (DropboxClientFactory.revokeClient(callback)).  An option is setting that variable to null.